# input Mat used in goodFeatureToTrack

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to detect feature in face with `goodFeatureToTrack` function in java. It always crashes there. This is my code:

```
Mat eyeRegion = detectCascade();//i used here cascadeclassifier to detect eye region
if(eyeRegion.empty())
    Log.i("face_calibrated","eye region is empty");
```

I make sure that my region is not empty.

```
if(eyeRegion.channels()==1) 
{
  //i convert my mat to rgb to detectfeatures
    Imgproc.cvtColor(eyeRegion, eyeRegion, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    Log.i("face_calibrated","eyeRegion is channel1");
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(eyeRegion,cornersA,4,0.01,5.0,null,3,false,0.04);
```

I have declared `cornersA` as global `MatOfPoint`

```
public MatOfPoint cornersA = new MatOfPoint();
```

What type of input mat (RGB or GRAY) should be used in this function?

Comment: Is it related to OpenCV java wrapper???

Comment: I have resolved it. My problem was that the eyeregion matrix should be Gray to pass it into goodfeatureToTrack.